# Set limited data from large data in reycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to set just four data from API in Recyclerview. The data from API are dynamic.If there are more than 4 data then the last one should hide itself and the recent data should appear at the top. I have researched but could not find the applicable solution.

My Adpater

```
public class EventRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
private ArrayList<String> start;
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener;
private ArrayList<String> desc;
private ArrayList<EventData>data;


public EventRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EventData> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.content_events, parent, false);

    return new EventRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.start.setText(data.get(position).getStartDate());

    holder.des.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(position).getName()));
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView start, des, viewall,name;

    private CardView cardView;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        start = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.startdate);

        des = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        viewall = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewall);




    }

}

}
```

I have set the data as follows

```
  private void initEventRecycler() {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    eventR.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    eventR.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    eventR.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    eventRecyclerAdapter = new EventRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, events);
    eventR.setAdapter(eventRecyclerAdapter);

}
```

Comment: Add your code and what you tried

Comment: I have edited the question @PierGiorgioMisley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have shorted data in the array list you are getting in adapter then use this code to show only 5 items.

```
  @Override
public int getItemCount() {
        if (data!= null && data.size() < 5) {
            return data.size();
        } else {
            return 5;
        }

 }
```

if you have a data list in random order then first short it from latest to old and send to adapter.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: This solution is not sufficient as performance aspect, You may have large data structure and only use first top 4 elements, You should find a way to keep only data that you need and update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
EventData[] mData = new EventData[4];
int writeIndex = 0;

public void add(Object o) {
  ring[writeIndex % ring.length] = o;
  writeIndex++;
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.lenght;
}
```

- You can also Check  [`ArrayCircularQueue.java`](https://www.scribd.com/doc/14768610/Array-Circular-Queue)